# transfer feeditem

Tags: apex, community

I have a button "transfer" on account. Upon clicking that button, the feeditem on account have to be transferred or migrated to its opportunity. Modifiying the parentid on FeedItem cannot be done as the field is not writebale. So how can this be done ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the ParentId when you are doing an insert so you will have to:

- query the existing items
- create a new `FeedItem` object for each item and copy the field values but set the ParentId to the Opportunity ID
- insert the new objects
- delete the old objects